# Poloniex API - Invalid API key\/secret pair

Tags: java, php, http, bitcoin, poloniex

I can't generate simple private request.

After 4 hour using Swift for it, I start trying to generate request in browser.

So I want to get all balances. `command=returnBalances`

Randome integer `nonce=23455`

That info together I have to convert to "HMAC-SHA512". So I use online generator - [quickhash.com](https://quickhash.com), choose *SHA-512(SHA2)*, choose "*Use HMAC Method*", put inside my API Key, and choose *Base64 encoding*.

After that, I have this - `fu66g4WfjyJOrjfPtmWoaZGn1v6NK+YeiiKklD5EWfkvfXpBeCQE41Cg7jemh/Q/1yaLBvkxhoX2vpe2949IOA==`

and then, I have to make link, for request. Okay:

> https://poloniex.com/tradingApi?Key=YF9RDYRK-GL29DI0T-8CE6292X-9OQ21A2P&Sign=fu66g4WfjyJOrjfPtmWoaZGn1v6NK+YeiiKklD5EWfkvfXpBeCQE41Cg7jemh/Q/1yaLBvkxhoX2vpe2949IOA==

**But I get error:**

```
{"error":"Invalid API key\/secret pair."}
```

**Can somebody help? Where my mistake?**

Comment: Be carefull to never enter Api Key or Api Secret anywhere on internet.

Comment: Yes, you should really change your Key/Secret pair now or anybody can have access to your account over the API.

Comment: Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 8):

You are doing a `GET`-request. You have to do a `POST`-request for private functions. From the [documentation](https://temp.poloniex.com/support/api/):

> All calls to the trading API are sent via HTTP POST to
>   https://poloniex.com/tradingApi and must contain the following
>   headers:
>
> ```
> Key - Your API key.
> Sign - The query's POST data signed by your key's "secret" according to the HMAC-SHA512 method.
> ```
>
> Additionally, all queries must include a "nonce" POST parameter. The
>   nonce parameter is an integer which must always be greater than the
>   previous nonce used.

That means `Key` and `Sign` are sent inside the HTTP-Headers. The rest (`command`, `nonce`) are part of the body.

Example request:

1. Let's say your API-Key is 123 and your API-Secret is 456.
2. The parameters for a request to `returnBalances` are `command=returnBalances&nonce=1473087174`. **Please note:** The `nonce`-parameter must be increased with every request. It is recommended to use the current timestamp.
3. You sign `command=returnBalances&nonce=1473087174` using HMAC-SHA512 and your secret (*456*). The result will be put into the `Sign`-Header.
4. You put your API-Key (*123*) into the `Key`-Header.
5. You put the request parameters `command=returnBalances&nonce=1473087174` into the request-body.
6. You send your request to *https://poloniex.com/tradingApi* using the `POST`-method **and** using *SSL-encryption*.

Doing this over your browser will not work unless you use third-party-software/plugins which allow you to modify the request-headers, etc.

Comment: I added a "Content-Length" to my request header. That resulted in me receiving the OP's error "{"error":"Invalid API key\/secret pair."}" despite the request being otherwise correct. Drove me mad!